# Socket.io not connecting and emitting in YouTube's IFrame API onStateChange

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, youtube-iframe-api, flask-socketio

I am using YouTube's [IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and Flask socket.io to embed and control a YouTube video. With the following code, `connectAndEmmit()` will execute and I will see the sent and recieved messages. The issue is when I try to call `connectAndEmmit()` from within `onPlayerStateChange()` or reference directly like so:

```js
let player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player("player", {
    height: "390",
    width: "640",
    videoId: "M7lc1UVf-VE",
    events: {
      onReady: onPlayerReady,
      onStateChange: () => socket.on("connect", function () {
        console.log("sent");

        socket.emit("controls-changed", {
          data: "content emmitted",
        });
      }),
    },
  });
}
```

Both will result in nothing emitted or received.

Below is the **working** JS file. When I move `connectAndEmmit()` inside of `onPlayerStateChange()` nothing is emitted.

```js
let socket = io.connect("http://" + document.domain + ":" + location.port);
function connectAndEmmit() {
  socket.on("connect", function () {
    console.log("sent");

    socket.emit("controls-changed", {
      data: "content emmitted",
    });
  });
}

socket.on("my response", function (msg) {
  console.log("received", msg);
});

let tag = document.createElement("script");

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
let firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

let player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player("player", {
    height: "390",
    width: "640",
    videoId: "M7lc1UVf-VE",
    events: {
      onReady: onPlayerReady,
      onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange,
    },
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  //event.target.playVideo();
}

$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let videoId = $("input.youtube-url")
    .val()
    .match(/v=(.+)/)[1];

  console.log(videoId);
  player.loadVideoById(videoId);
});

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (
    event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING ||
    event.data === YT.PlayerState.PAUSED
  ) {
    console.log("state", event.target.getPlayerState());
    console.log("time", event.target.getCurrentTime());
  }
}

connectAndEmmit();
```

Lastly, and interestingly, when I stop the local server and restart, I see all the emissions I was expecting. But again do not see them when everything is running when calling from within `onPlayerStateChange()`

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to create a new Socket.IO connection every time the player state changes? There is a limit of active connections a page can have, and you are not disposing of the connections that you make when you don't need them anymore.

Comment: Good point. When I tried to wrap everything in the `socket.on("connect", function () { });` then emit on change I had bigger issues where the IFrame wouldn't show up at all. My goal would be to connect once then emit onStateChange if a few conditions are met.

Comment: Right, so why move the connection call inside the handler? It should be outside. Move only the emit inside the handler.

Comment: My understanding is the socket must emit from within the connection call. In order to emit from the event handler I had to move the entire IFrame inside that connection call as well. When doing that the entire IFrame didn't show up.